# Make only one API call for two separate functions on the same page and pull from sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, session-storage, ab-testing

I'm using Adobe Target and have come to a point where I might have two or more experiments appear in any given browser window at one time. For those of you not aware, an experiment is basically a series of front end HTML blocks (html, css, js), which load after the server-side mark-up in order to manipulate the DOM for various types of A-B testing and personalisation.

Each different experiment makes it's own API call. I have developed a solution that performs a search for a sessionStorage item called 'sparksSSO' and if it doesn't exist, then it will make an API call, if it does exist, it will run the rest of the function from variables that pull the sessionStorage data (confused yet?)

My solution works if I copy/paste in a test URL of each of the various experiments into the same browser tab, because, alas the data does infact exist in sessionStorage.

However when they all appear on the same page at the same time, ie two js code blocks which contain the same logic to check for session storage and then take action from there, they seem to run the logic as though the first function doesn't store the API call into sessionStorage and then subsequently, the second function ignores that sparksSSO (the sessionStorage variable) exists and it makes a fresh API call, when it should infact recognise that the API call has occured and it should now run it's function from sessionStorage.

Here is a simplified version of the scripts to illustrate my issue - both the same, except the naming convention - one is exp33 and the other is exp78:

```
<script>
//# sourceURL=EXP33_target.js - THIS ONE RUNS FIRST
// declares sparksSSO as global variable and converts from strigified API data, back to JSON object
var sparksSSO = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('sparksSSO')) || {};
// create #home_dashboard as a variable  
var home_dashboard = document.querySelector('#home_dashboard');
// global variables for use with session storage
var sparksOfferCount = (sparksSSO.totalOffers >= 0) ? sparksSSO.totalOffers : "" ;
var sparksAllOffers = (sparksSSO.allOffers);
var sparksDashImg;
  
function api_call_exp33() {
  if ("sparksSSO" in sessionStorage) {
    // runs function with variable data populated by session storage
  } else { ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // funs API call and functions from fresh API data
  } // closes ELSE IF statement if sparksSSO is in session storage
} // closes api_call_exp33 function
</script>

<script>
//# sourceURL=EXP78_target_foundIT.js - THIS ONE RUNS SECOND AND SHOULD RECOGNISE sparksSSO, but it doesn't
// declares sparksSSO as global variable and converts from strigified API data, back to JSON object
var sparksSSO = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('sparksSSO')) || {};
// create #home_dashboard as a variable  
var home_dashboard = document.querySelector('#home_dashboard');
// global variables for use with session storage
var sparksOfferCount = (sparksSSO.totalOffers >= 0) ? sparksSSO.totalOffers : "" ;
var sparksAllOffers = (sparksSSO.allOffers);
var sparksDashImg;
  
function api_call_exp78() {
  if ("sparksSSO" in sessionStorage) {
    // runs function with variable data populated by session storage
  } else { ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // funs API call and functions from fresh API data
  } // closes ELSE IF statement if sparksSSO is in session storage
} // closes api_call_exp78 function
</script>
```

Any ideas, folks?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that an overcomplicated description of the problem. What you describe boils down to two options.

1. The code does not actually enter api_call as shown.
2. ... or the if does not trigger.

Assuming variant 2 it is just a question of why 'in' is false. So print session storage (watch asynchronous logging, so may stringify) and check if the key exists at the time of the call. Maybe you are checking the wrong level, maybe you are on object level instead of content level. Object.keys() can help.

Anyway none of the surrounding info seems in any way relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out in the end that there wasn't anything wrong with the code posted above. Each of the scripts were wrapped in a setTimeout statement (not shown here in the thread) and both were set to fire at 500 miliseconds...hence...they were running at the same time, rather than sequentially. I added a 1500 milisecond delay to the second script (ie, give the browser a second to retrieve the API data from the first script call) and it worked right away.